# How to tag per branch?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in my repo: `master` and `next`.

How can I tag version per branch?

I mean when I check the `next` branch and go to `tags` tab, I want to show the next tag's.
[image]

Right now I use:

```
 git tag v1.0 next
 git push origin --tags
```

But tab show the v1.0 for both: `master` and `next`. I expected to see this tag only when I select `next` branch.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag is a *fixed* name for a single commit. It is an independent concept and tags have no relation to branches. It is not possible to do what you want to do.

Behind the scenes:

- commit: abc123def456
- branch "next": "refs/heads/next" -> "abc123def456"
- branch "v1": "refs/tags/v1" -> "abc123def456"

Comment: so if you have two environments, `next` and `prod` how do you tag the version of the each release? (I use monorepo)

Comment: Find a different way, e.g. suffixes for your tags or organize them in namespaces: `v1-next` or `next/v1`

Answer (score 1):

Branches and tags are independent from each other. You don't need to think for combining them. You can specify each branch name individually and independently.
Branch name can be

```
    master
    dev
    production
    product_dev
    product_alpha
```

Or you can give name tags such as below from any branch

```
v1.0.0
v2.0.3_beta
v3.0.0_alpha
v3.0.5_
v4.0.0_
```